# Rails Engine: How to auto reload class upon each request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a Rails engine that allows the implementer to put classes in `app/snippets`.

From within the engine, I want to instruct the host Rails app to auto reload classes in `app/snippets` upon each request so that the implementer doesn't have to restart the server when making changes.

I understand there's a `config.to_prepare` initialization event I can hook into, but I can't get access to the `app.root` like I an in an `initializer` block. In other words:

```
initializer 'something' do |app|
  # I need app.root to derive app/snippets
end

config.to_prepare do
  # Can't get app.root from here
end
```

How can I auto reload classes in `app/snippets` upon each request?

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?