# How can I get Rails development server to reload my class upon changes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this class that the server is not picking up changes to unless I kill the server and reload it. All my other classes are automatically updated. How can I get the Rails server (WebBrick) to pick up changes to this class without having to kill the server?

I saw this questions but I'm not using a module: [Rails 3.2.x: how to reload app/classes dir during development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471543/rails-3-2-x-how-to-reload-app-classes-dir-during-development)

I saw this question but it had no answers: [Rails Engine: How to auto reload class upon each request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11851315/rails-engine-how-to-auto-reload-class-upon-each-request)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  require 'PaymentGateway'
  def method
   result = PaymentGateway::capture
```

This is the class I want to automatically reload upon change. It is in the same directory as app/controllers/

```
class PaymentGateway < ApplicationController 
  def self.capture
```

Rails 4.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't use `require`. That's only for 3rd party libraries.
2. Change filename to `snake_case.rb`. Rails will pick up changes automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You code has some problems at first.

1. `require` inside a class does nothing. To get mixins, use `include` or `extend`
2. A class is not for include or extend. Module does.
3. You don't need to require a file in '/app`

I don't know what's your real purpose, if you want to reuse the method in `PaymentGateway`, set it as a module and get it included in others.

```
module PaymentGateway
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def capture
      # ...
    end
  end
end

# Then in controller
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include PaymentGateway
end
```

By this change, on each request to UsersController's actions, the include macro will be executed at runtime and you don't need to restart server.

Comment: Without the `require`, it would give this error: `uninitialized constant UsersController::PaymentGateway`

Comment: @Chioe, try `include ::PaymentGateway`

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things I would suggest.

First, The `PaymentGateway` class should be part of `lib/payment_gateway` so that it can be used in any part of your application.

Second, use controller inheritance pattern if you want polymorphic controllers

```
class BaseController < ApplicationController
end

class UsersController < BaseController
end
```

Comment: I should put it in /lib/ even though it is not a 3rd party source? I don't want polymorphic controllers; I just tried to extend ApplicationController to get it to reload automatically. I thought maybe the server only looks at instances of ApplicationController.